# Web API Custom Filter / Attribute Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following filter:

```
public class CPUAPIAuthorize : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (CPUContext.Current == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Applied to the following web api method:

```
[HttpGet]
[CPUAPIAuthorize]
[ExceptionHandling]
public dynamic GetPrograms()
{
   .... removed ....
}
```

However, If i put a breakpoint in the `if (CPUContext.Current == null)` its not catching, which leads me to believe that attribute isn't firing.

I've also noticed that my custom `ExceptionHandling` attribute isn't firing, and I can remove all attributes and the web api method will function. Whereas in the past I was required to have the `HttpGet` attribute there or the method wouldn't execute.

I'm at a loss as to why the filters/attributes aren't firing.

**What is CPUContext.Current?**

To help clarify, CPUContext.Current holds the current logged in user.. here is the method. I use this same setup on other projects that work fine w/ the above attributes.

```
public static class CPUContext
{
    public static CommunityPartnerUser Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("_currentCPU"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("_currentCPU", Authentication.AuthenticateCPUser());
            }

            return HttpContext.Current.Items["_currentCPU"] as CommunityPartnerUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell me the full namespace path to the `ActionFilterAttribute`  standard class derived by your own base class

Comment: System.Web.Http.Filters - i've already checked this :)

Comment: It's the first step check, you know ;)

Comment: Can you share the code of `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`? At least, some kind of pseudo-code?

Comment: `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` is actually part of the .Net framework - `System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute` to be exact. So unfortunately I cannot :(

Comment: Ah, ok ok, sorry, I thought it was some custom filter...

Comment: I would say that if `OnAuthorization` doesn't fire, it should be something with the request. I mean: some missing header, or who knows what.

Comment: Yea - it's weird as i've used this exact same code in like 3 or 4 other projects with zero issues. For some reason this project is reacting completely different. The web api method will successfully execute, however it seems like all the attributes are ignored.

Comment: Try some custom filter and see if it works...

Comment: It was my understanding that what I was using was a custom filter - maybe i'm confused on what they are

Comment: I mean: try to create a custom filter which directly derives `ActionFilterAttribute` :D

Comment: What is `CPUContext.Current`? Is your debugger actually loading symbols?

Comment: Have you tried implementing OnAuthorizationAsync? Have you tried applyin gthe attribute at the controller level, or resgitering it globally in the api configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up fixing the problem was running nuget updates on the Microsoft ASP.Net Web API package and the  - after doing so the OnAuthorization method started to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to name your attibute  CPUAPIAuthorizeAttribute to make it work. Due to some naming guidelines
And just the attribute as it is over GetPrograms

Comment: I've appened "Attribute" to the attribute class name but still no luck.

Comment: try to derive from instead ActionFilterAttribute  if that does not work then i am  out of ideas :/

Answer (score 0):

To better diagnose the problem:
When you put a breakpoint on the first line of GetPrograms() do you hit it?

If no, then either your debug symbols haven't been loaded properly or your request is handled by another controller. You can easily determine which is the case by throwing a new Exception() at the beginning of GetPrograms().

If you hit the breakpoint, then the next thing is to determine why you don't hit the breakpoint in your custom attribute. You said you put it inside the if statement, please put the breakpoint on the first line of the attribute instead, to rule out that the reason you don't hit it is because CPUContext.Current is actually not null.